# Schema published but not seen in BI Server with jpivot

Tags: pentaho

I created an schema in Schema Workbench and publish with no errors, but when I got in BI Server with the standard user admin, I choose New->jpivot, then it display the name of the schema I created but it does not display the cube. For reference the error I get from catalina.out is:

17:11:45,174 ERROR [PentahoDataSourceResolver] PentahoXmlaServlet.ERROR_0002 - IDatasourceService.UNABLE_TO_INSTANTIATE_OBJECT
org.pentaho.platform.api.data.DBDatasourceServiceException: javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: Name [Esquema Salario] is not bound in this Context. Unable to find [Esquema Salario].

Comment: Is "Esquema Salario" a DB connection used by your cube? Looks like this connection can't be found on the server.

Comment: Yes "Esquema Salario" is connected to mysql, with Schema Workbench the mysql connection is Ok and also the cube. Something else, in the server I connect to mysql but I cannot complete the task because in the step when I have to relate the fact and dimension tables it does not display the tables' attributes. Thank yo very much in advance

Comment: Sorry, not sure if I understood you. Usually, you don't have to relate fact and dimension tables to create a JDBC datasource connection for the cube. You just have to specify things like dbms type, db name, url and user/password. In other words you have to define connection on the server the same way as you did it in Schema Workbench. It should be done in "File > Manage > Data Source -> (+) -> JDBC". Alternatively, it may be specified in JNDI connection in web.xml file. Can you please add information about connections on your server?

Comment: The Pentaho version is the community one 6.X, How do I create the JNDI connection to relate Schema Workbench with BI Server in order to see the cube?. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Sorry for late response. I don't know how to share JNDI configuration between Schema Workbench and BI Server. But you may create JDBC data source on BI server with same properties as your JDNI datasource for Schema Workbench (see here how to create it: https://help.pentaho.com/Documentation/6.1/0H0/060/010/030/000, alternative way is here: https://help.pentaho.com/Documentation/6.1/0H0/060/010/030/020). Try to create a datasource with name Esquema Salario on the server. Your cube should appear then, or at least it will give a different error.

Comment: Hi, In Pentaho BI Server I choose File -> New -> Data Source, In Data Source Name I wrote "Esquema Salario", and in Source Tye I choose "Database Table(s)", then I create a connection "cone1", and in the same screen I choose "Reporting an Analysis ..." and then "Next", after that I choose the dimension tables and the fact table, I choose the Fact table and then "Next", but in this step "define Joins", it doesn´t let me because I choose a table an its attributes does not display, then I cannot create a JDBC connection. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

`Name [Esquema Salario] is not bound in this Context` errors usually appear if you use JNDI name, which is not defined on your system. So, I assumed, that this is the name of the datasource, which you reference while publishing Mondrian schema files to BI server.

Xml file with Mondrian schema definition generated by Schema Workbench does not contain any information regarding how to connect to database. So, you need to specify these details when you upload your schema file on BI server (It's done on step 4 below).

But first you have to create the connection itself (steps 1-2):

1. Create new JDBC datasource:[image: Create new JDBC datasource]
2. Define connection parameters: [image: Define connection parameters]
3. If cubes still don't appear after these steps, you may republish your cube: follow same steps as in step 1, but select "Analysis" instead of "JDBC" in the end.
4. Upload the xml file, generated by schema workbench and select the datasource, which you have created on step 2. [image: Publish mondrian schema].
5. If cube still does not appear - check your log again. If you see the same `Name is not bound` error, you may try to restart your BI server application (new connections usually get recongnized immediately, but if you had a connection with same name before, than you might need to restart tomcat).

If that does not work, than once again, check log files. I guess, you'll have some different error in this case.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem as the OP (blank screen when clicking New View) with the latest version of **Pentaho BI server 7.1** (latest at the moment) and even with the **6.0 version** one, **Pivot4J SNAPSHOT 1.0 plug in version** (latest as of today), **Schema Workbech 3.14** (latest as of today).

And as, in line with OP, my `catalina.out` log was also spitting the `Name [DatasourceName] is not bound in this Context. Unable to find [DatasourceName]`.

After several trials and errors I noticed the problem showed up when I checked the "Register the XMLA Data Source" when publishing the schema on Schema Workbench. So to fix the problem I just unchecked it before publishing.

Another way to fix this is going to the Manage Datasources option on the BI server, Import Analysis, choosing the schema created by Schema Workbench, **AND** manually setting the data source parameter value `EnableXmla` to `false` and saving changes. Now the schema should show up when clicking on Create New > Pivot4J view.